# WinError 2 when installing isda_daycounters from GitHub

Tags: python, git, github, pip

I'm trying to install isda_daycounters from GitHub using the below

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/miradulo/isda_daycounters.git
```

I get a message saying it's been cloned, and then I get:

```
 Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/miradulo/isda_daycounters.git
```

It's my first install from GitHub so I'm having trouble figuring out the error. I read that it could be because there's no setup.py file, under the "pull requests" tab it looks like one has been created but I can't see it in the actual code folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bpip%5D+pull+request

Comment: `pip install numpy install git+https://github.com/miradulo/isda_daycounters.git@refs/pull/6/merge`